# Why did accelerated vesting apply to the CEO but not regular employees of Twitter?

Tags: united-states, stocks, vesting, executive-compensation

The Twitter acquisition made the CEO, Parag Agarwal very rich because his unvested shares seem to have vested on an "accelerated schedule". But for regular employees, I read there were concerns some of them would get fired before their stocks vested after the acquisition. So it seems they didn't get the accelerated vesting. How is it that the CEO got this accelerated vesting benefit but other employees didn't? Is that something he would have negotiated for?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Based on [news reports](https://www.washingtonpost.com/business/2022/10/29/twitter-executives-payouts-musk/), this was a "golden parachute" within his contract that accelerated his equity awards if he were terminated within 12 months of a "change of control". It's not uncommon in executive contracts; most other employees were likely either "at-will" (no contract) employees or did not have such a clause in their contracts.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141023/discussion-on-answer-by-d-stanley-why-did-accelerated-vesting-apply-to-the-ceo-b).